# issues with backslash apostrophe escape characters in swift string copied from clipboard

Tags: ios, swift, character-encoding

I am having issues with using the AWS AppSync SDK creating mutations from a swift String.  The issue only occurs when I paste text including apostrophes in a textView and send to the SDK.

If I type text with apostrophes in the textView and then assign that messageTextView.text to my mutation it works fine.

however if I paste some text including the apostrophe and then assign that messageTextView.text to my mutation it returns an error:

```
[Unable to parse the JSON document: 'Unrecognized character escape ''' (code 39)
 at [Source: (String)"
```

Is there anyway to remove these backslash escape characters from the Swift string obtained from the textView prior to creating the mutation?

I have tried to define the string as String(messageTextView.text) but that did not help.

The exact same string typed out with apostrophe in the textView and the one copied to the textView from clipboard are different. I would like to know how to make them the same.  ie to make the one pasted be like the one typed out.  I assume the difference is the encoding but I don't know enough about the Swift string encodings to fix the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If anyone comes across this the problem was the unicodeScalars value of the pasted text was: "\'" for the apostrophe.  For the typed text the value is "\u{2019}"

So to solve this problem I did the following in textViewDidChange:

```
textView.text = textView.text.replacingOccurrences(of: "\'", with: "\u{2019}")
```